# missing sharedStrings.xml when saved with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, calc

I create a `calc` file using `libreoffice` whose structure is as follows:

```
@mosby:/temp/aa/xl# ls -R
.:
[Content_Types].xml  docProps  _rels  xl

./docProps:
app.xml  core.xml  custom.xml

./_rels:

./xl:
_rels  sharedStrings.xml  styles.xml  workbook.xml  worksheets

./xl/_rels:
workbook.xml.rels

./xl/worksheets:
sheet1.xml  sheet3.xml  sheet5.xml  sheet7.xml
sheet2.xml  sheet4.xml  sheet6.xml  sheet8.xml
```

Then through `python` and `openpyxl` I work on that file after which I save it

```
wb = load_workbook(file_name)
[...]
wb.save(file_name)
```

The problem is that the `sharedStrings.xml` file is gone while I need it for other applications that don't use `openpyxl`. Is there a switch that forces `openpyxl` to use the original structure in the save?

The other tool I use to work with calc files is `xml.dom.minidom` but it doesn't allow me to save the files

Comment: Basically a calc file is a zip file. You could unzip it, get the `sharedStrings.xml` file and add it to the archive any time. As a workaround. I don't know if it will work in your case, though.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich It does not work for two reasons: 1) the work is done by a program that if after unzipping the calc file does not find the `sharedStrings.xml` file it does not know where to get it. 2) the aforementioned file is not updated if during the work I add or remove values ​​not present in the original